# Pandas append if groupby sum condition is met

Tags: python, pandas

Apologies if this is a repeated question Im not sure the specific syntax of what I want to do.

I would like to iterate through large df where A and B are Index values and x,y,z are data columns

```
df=
A  B     x  y  z
0.1 0.2  2  2  0
0.1 0.3  1  3  0
0.1 0.4  3  3  0
0.2 0.2  4  1  -1
0.2 0.3  5  3  0
0.2 0.1  6  1  0
0.3 0.2  1  1  0
0.3 0.5  1  2  0
0.3 0.7  2  1  0
```

If the following condition is met:

```
df.groupby('A')['z'].sum()==0
```

Append this whole groupby object to a new df or produce a df of all the groupby obj that fulfill this condition.

Expected output:

```
new_df=

A   B    x  y   z 
0.1 0.2  2  2   0
0.1 0.3  1  3   0
0.1 0.4  3  3   0
0.3 0.2  1  1   0
0.3 0.5  1  2   0
0.3 0.7  2  1   0
```

I'm trying something like

```
new_df = df.loc[df.groupby('A')['z'].sum())==0]
```

but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Do a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) using `level=0` in combination with [`transfrom`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) and then do a subset of the dataframe based on the boolean `mask`

```
mask = df.groupby(level=0)['z'].transform(lambda s: s.sum()==0)

new_df = df[mask].copy()

new_df
#          x  y  z
# A   B           
# 0.1 0.2  2  2  0
#     0.3  1  3  0
#     0.4  3  3  0
# 0.3 0.2  1  1  0
#     0.5  1  2  0
#     0.7  2  1  0
```